# Object ... has no method 'append' -Need help quick

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am currently attempting to write a function that applies unique ids to list item dynamically by ticking checkboxes, though I have encountered a problem, when appending the unique id to the list item I get the following error message in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object SpTU 4, 183:false<br /> has no method 'append'
```

Here is the code that is causing the error:

```
strng += name+":"+val+"<br />";
var i = 1;
strng.append($({ type: "text", id:+i }));
```

I need help with this quickly so any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advance

-------EDIT----------
Here is the whole function so it is easier to understand, I am new to programming to it may be very messy and unproffesional.

```
var dataToShow = {};
function check(tickbox){
  dataToShow[tickbox.value] = tickbox.checked == true;
  showDataOnScreen(dataToShow);


function showDataOnScreen(dataToShow){
var $strng = "";
jQuery.each(dataToShow,function(name,val){
    $strng += name+":"+val+"<br />";
    var i = 1;
    $strng.append($({ type: "text", id:+i }));
    });

jQuery("#list").html(strng);
```

Comment: Alex, what is in your `strng` variable?

Comment: Strings don't have an `.append` method... what are you trying to do with `$({ type: "text", id:+i })`? I have never seen such a usage of jQuery. It seems you are completely mixing HTML strings and jQuery. You might find it helpful to read some jQuery tutorials: http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials.

Comment: It is a string that is added to a list when a checkbox is selected:                   jQuery("#list").html(strng);

Comment: You'll need to give us more code or more information. That snippet just doesn't make sense.

Comment: Tip: Dont use jQuery until you understand JS basics.

Comment: OK I have updated the question to show you the full function

Comment: Could you provide an example of the string `$strng` contains and of the final HTML you want to get?

Comment: Are you thinking about Python? JavaScript doesn't provide `append` for strings.

Comment: Ok then, is there a way to convert the string into an object?

Comment: Also, you are missing at least 2 closing function braces (`}`), which will cause problems.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that strng is a JQUERY object, assuming you are using JQUERY

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to build a list of checked items, I would go about it this way.

```
// create an array to store the checked items
var checkedItems = new Array();

// loop through the checked check boxes contained in the list element
// and add them to the array
$("#list :checked").each(function (){
    var item = { name: $(this).attr("name"), value: $(this).val() };
    checkedItems.push(item);
});
```

Or, even better, if you plan on displaying the results in a different element, you can cut out the array.

```
// loop through the checked check boxes contained in the list element
// and add them to a different element
$("#list :checked").each(function (){
    var item = "<div>"+ $(this).attr("name") + ": " + $(this).val() + "</div>";
    $("#selectedList").append(item);
});
```

[Here's a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/jrummell/ZcNQ4/) on jsFiddle.

References:

- Array: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array
- jQuery each(): http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/
- jQuery :checked selector: http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/
- jQuery append(): http://api.jquery.com/append/

Comment: Absolutely pointless giving them code when they have no idea what it means.

Comment: @Alex ... which is why my answer is well commented and has links to references. Using this information, an inexperienced web developer who is willing to learn should be able to figure it out.